How to unit test Mapper provided by MapStruct?
I want to unit test my MapStruct mappers, if that is a thing, should I use Mockito, or can I just call mapper = new UserMapperImpl();.
UserMapperTest.java
class UserMapperTest {

    private UserMapper mapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mapper = new UserMapperImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldMapUserSignUpDtoToUser() {

    }
    
}


UserMapper.java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "username", target = "displayName"),
            @Mapping(target = "profilePicture", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "password", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "role", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "pictures", ignore = true)
    })
    User toUser(UserSignUpDto userDto);
    @Mapping(source = "email", target = "displayName")
    User toUser(UserLogInDto userDto);

    UserSignUpDto toUserLogInDto(User user);
    UserLogInDto toUserSignUpDto(User user);
    UserProfileDto toUserProfileDto(User user);

}


I don't think Mockito would be appropriate.  If UserMapperImpl is stateless you probably can get away with not creating it for each test.  I would use a real mapper and assert that the output of the methods is the expected output for the given input.  As a side note I would advise against using the suffix Impl in class names that implement an interface, it doesn't convey any useful information.

@Gavin  the implementation is generated by MapStruct

In which case I would create a new instance for each test as you have shown, but I would still test that each method produces the expected output for the given input.  I might even consider using a parameterised test method.

I am testing my Mappers using mockito and simply Mappers.get(
class UserMapperTest {

    private UserMapper mapper = Mappers.get(UserMapper.class);

    @Test
    public void shouldMapUserSignUpDtoToUser() {

    }

}

for 99% of all cases that is enought. I would suggest using mockito since it significantly reduces test runtime since there is no spring context to be started.

The correct method is now Mappers.getMapper(...
